# Firebase Crashlytics - setting User ID is not working?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

A useful feature from Crashlytics by Firebase is to set a userID for a session, to later look up that particular user's crash events.

It doesn't seem to be working in my Android app however. I am debugging with my device. Here is the DebugView of my device:

[image]

Where the user_id is properly set via setUserID on the Firebase Analytics object.

I then triggered a crash. But...

[image]

It can't find my userID? (I can find the crash I triggered though.)

I don't even know what else to try, according to DebugView the userID was properly set?

Comment: same issue in flutter please help
here is code:-
`await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
                                .setUserIdentifier("Device ID:-${deviceId!}");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it was as simple as:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setUserId(uuid); // wrong
Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(uuid);                // correct
```

Was overlooking "FirebaseCrashlytics" vs "FirebaseAnalytics" https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android

Comment: It is not like the 1st one is wrong. You may need both, right?

Comment: `FirebaseCrashlytics` has been updated to `Crashlytics.crashlytics().setUserID(uuid)`

Comment: @JCarlosR , you actually don't need both. The first is to log Analytics data for Firebase Events/Google Analytics. The second one is to log crash (Crashlytics) events.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup user id in screen which will open everytime when user opens an app like dashboard screen.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
            .setUserIdentifier("${userID}");
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting first crash on installed application, you can search with the user id in Firebase Crashlytics

```java
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(uuid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(uuid);` in all screens (activities). If you add only in login screen then userid will not share to crashlytics, when app is crashed after reopening. Since we will ask user to login only once.

Answer (score 0):

In Sep 2021 using -

- com.google.firebase:firebase-bom - version 28.4.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx - version 19.0.1
- com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx - version 18.2.1

I resolved this with :                     FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId();